# Google Contacts Api Getting contacts in a certain group. (The my contacts group)

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

So I can get all my contacts with this:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=mytoken&alt=json&v=3
```

And all my groups with this:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full?access_token=myToken&alt=json&v=3
```

And I can get the actual contact group for "myContacts" with this:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/base/6?access_token=mytoken&alt=json&v=3
```

**But how can I get all the contacts in the myContacts group? The previous query just gives me the actual group.**

Comment: Please don't use [tag:google-chrome-app] if your question is in no way specific for them. It's just an unrelated API question.

Comment: True but I'm calling this code from within a chrome app. I thought there might be a trick to it in that scenario.

Comment: You can get all the contacts by retrieving all contacts: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below URI in order to get the contacts of a specific group.

`href="http://www.google.com/feeds/contacts/groups/userEmail/base/1234b"/`

For reference and more information check the documentation of the Google Contacts API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters) in the *Retrieving contacts using query parameters* section.

The query parameters (including the group of course) that you may use are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters) in the  *Contacts query parameters reference*.

Comment: href="http://www.google.com/feeds/groups/userEmail/base/1234b"/ this is the proper uri.

Answer (score 2):

Your request - `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=mytoken&alt=json&v=3`

Group id - `http://www.google.com/feeds/contacts/groups/userEmail/base/1234b`

Then call to GET contacts of group

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=mytoken&alt=json&v=3&group=http://www.google.com/feeds/groups/userEmail/base/1234b
```

Comment: Above query doesn't work - because in the group uri you are using contacts/groups. Edited the answer - check it out.