# Retrieve group contact from google contact in php

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

Already I have followed the instruction of https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact_group for group data.

But whenever I tried to fetch group wise data using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full, I only got the group id in the given array what they provided not the other data (like name, mobile number).

One of the given array is given below for better understand

```
[0] => Array
(
    [gd$etag] => "YDwreyM."
    [id] => Array
        (
            [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com/base/6
        )

    [updated] => Array
        (
            [$t] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
        )

    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                    [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#group
                )

        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [$t] => System Group: My Contacts
        )

    [content] => Array
        (
            [$t] => System Group: My Contacts
        )

    [link] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => self
                    [type] => application/atom+xml
                    [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com/full/6?v=3.0
                )

        )

    [gContact$systemGroup] => Array
        (
            [id] => Contacts
        )

)
```

Don't get the other value like ['gd$name'] or ['gd$phoneNumbe'].

What should I do now ?

If any query please ask in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this url:

```
href="http://www.google.com/feeds/contacts/groups/userEmail/base/1234b"/
```

Use this for retrieving contacts using [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters) (*including group*).

References:

- [gContact:groupMembershipInfo](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#groupMembershipInfo)
- [Contacts Data API parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters)
- [Google Contacts Api Getting contacts in a certain group. (The my contacts group)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433829/5995040)
- [Google Contact API Fetch Contacts related to a Contact Group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29591149/5995040)

Hope this helps.